# Retrieving all the NSSet element values in a one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a one to many relationship as shown in the attached image. I want to list down all the course titles a particular lecturer teaches and the solution i have come up so far is as follows.

[image]

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Lecturer"];
    NSMutableSet *courseList = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'smith'"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *lecturers = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                                      error:&error];       
    for (Lecturer *lecturer in lecturers)
    {
        NSSet *set = lecturer.courses;

        for (Course *course in set)
        {
            [courseList addObject:course.title];
        }
    }
```

The courseList object contains all the courses a given lecturer teaches.
IS there a better way to do this using nspredicates alone and not by using 2 for loops ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just fetch the Course objects directly, but specifying a different predicate that requires their `authorname.name` to match:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Course"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"authorname.name == 'smith'"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *courseList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If you want an array with just the titles, you can then use:

```
NSArray *courseTitles = [courseList valueForKeyPath:@"title"];
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve only the courses not the course object list ?

Comment: cant i use propertiesToFetch to do that ?

Comment: You can, but it won't quite work how you would hope.  If you use `propertiesToFetch` on its own, then you still get an array of NSManagedObjects back, but their "other" attributes (i.e. not the ones you specify) will only be fetched if you specifically access them.  If you also specify `resultType` of `NSDictionaryResultType`, then you will get back an array of dictionaries - you will still need to use the `title` key to actually access the values you are after.